# How to do the fusion of two parallel branch in an encoder design?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

It seems I am not designing my encoder correctly, that is why I need the expert opinion on this since I am beginner to transformers and DL model design.

I have two different types of Transformers networks in an encoder as follows:

[image]

The embedding dimension of each branch is 256 and they are fused by a Linear layer

```
 self.fusion_head = nn.Linear(2*self.num_features, self.num_features) #self_num_features = 256
```

I have a forward feature function in my encoder

```
def transformer_forward(self,x):
    """

    :param x: The embeddings + pos_embed
    :return:
    """

    x_t1 = self.transformer_type1(x)  # torch.Size([1, 1280, 256])

    x_t2 = self.transformer_type2.forward(x)  # torch.Size([1, 1280, 256])

    # x = x_t1 + x_t2
    x = torch.cat([x_t1,x_t2],dim=2)

    x = self.fusion_head(x)

    return x
```

However, after training the models and loading the checkpoints, I realized that the `self.fusion_head` is place after `transformer_type1` modules

.
... 3.0.fn.to_qkv.weight', 'module.encoder.transformer_type1.3.layers.3.0.fn.to_out.0.weight', 'module.encoder.transformer_type1.3.layers.3.0.fn.to_out.0.bias', 'module.encoder.transformer_type1.3.layers.3.1.norm.weight', 'module.encoder.transformer_type1.3.layers.3.1.norm.bias', 'module.encoder.transformer_type1.3.layers.3.1.fn.net.0.weight', 'module.encoder.transformer_type1.3.layers.3.1.fn.net.0.bias', 'module.encoder.transformer_type1.3.layers.3.1.fn.net.3.weight', 'module.encoder.transformer_type1.3.layers.3.1.fn.net.3.bias', 'module.encoder.mlp_head.0.weight', 'module.encoder.mlp_head.0.bias', 'module.encoder.mlp_head.1.weight', 'module.encoder.mlp_head.1.bias', **'module.encoder.fusion_head.weight', 'module.encoder.fusion_head.bias',** 'module.encoder.transformer_type2.pos_embed', 'module.encoder.transformer_type2.patch_embed.proj.weight', 'module.encoder.transformer_type2.patch_embed.proj.bias', 'module.encoder.transformer_type2.patch_embed.norm.weight', 'module.encoder.transformer_type2.patch_embed.norm.bias', 'module.encoder.transformer_type2.blocks.0.norm1.weight', 'module.encoder.transformer_type2.blocks.0.norm1.bias', 'module.encoder.transformer_type2.blocks.0.filter.complex_weight', 'module.encoder.transformer_type2.blocks.0.norm2.weight', 'module.encoder.transformer_type2.blocks.0.norm2.bias', 'module.encoder.transformer_type2.blocks.0.mlp.fc1.weight',  ...

Is the placing of this concatenation layer (i.e., `fusion_head` correct in the forward function? why it is placed after `transformet_type1`? Should not `fusion_head` layer be after both `transformet_type1` and `transformer_type2` in terms of order?

Comment: The `__init__` defines the order of the modules.

Comment: @cronoik can you please elaborate more and share some examples? At least I can follow the example and find out where I am making mistakes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see there is the implementation of [`__repr__`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/9af3f98faf321f3f3a4c2e361fe115ebab125664/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L2480) of nn.Module. It prints the modules that you registered inside the `__init__` method of your network. That the `forward` method does not define the order, makes sense because you can call modules several times or not at all inside `forward`.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
class Bla(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b1 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.b2 = nn.GELU()
        self.b3 = nn.Linear(128,5)
        self.b0 = nn.Embedding(100,256)
    def forward(self, x):
        emb = self.b0(x)
        emb = self.b1(emb)
        emb = self.b2(emb)
        emb = self.b3(emb)
        return emb

net = Bla()
print(net)
```

Output:

```
Bla(
  (b1): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=128, bias=True)
  (b2): GELU(approximate='none')
  (b3): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=5, bias=True)
  (b0): Embedding(100, 256)
)
```

Comment: thanks, should we design the order in `__ini__` or the order does not affect the training in forward() ?

Comment: The order inside `__init__` doesn't affect the training, but I like to keep it consistent and usually register them in the order of the data flow (i.e. printing the model architecture should tell me something about the data flow). @S.EB

Comment: Don't worry. No problem ;)

Comment: Can you please have a look into my other question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77426965/how-to-add-up-two-different-losses-in-a-correct-way-when-the-difference-between?noredirect=1#comment136500631_77426965)? Thanks @cronoik