# How to add up two different losses in a correct way when the difference between two is large?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I have two different losses for training the model. `L1` loss is computed as:

```
recon_loss += F.l1_loss(pred_values, masked_patches) / total_num_masked
```

and another customized loss function for my model, that computes the loss for two 3D data cubes, `new_criterion = MyLoss(...)`. These two losses are added with weight:

```
# apply pixel-level loss
l1_weight = 0.1
errG = recon_loss * l1_w

new_loss = new_criterion(recon_cube, orig_cube).to(device)
errF_weight = 1.0
errF = new_loss * errF_weight

loss_total = errG + errGF
```

The output of two-loss functions is as follows:

```
(Pdb) errF
tensor(0.8987, grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
(Pdb) errG
tensor(2.4668e-05, grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
```

It seems the difference between two loss values is quite big and giving a lower weight to `F.L1` (recon_loss), it becomes smaller.

1. Is this value difference (i.e. smaller value (2.4668e-05) vs. larger value (0.8987), and then adding them together to obtain `loss_total` will affect the training? If yes, how do we resolve this and make sure the model trains well, benefiting from both losses?
2. How normally two different losses are added up together to train a model?

Comment: I've not worked with multi-loss problems before, but intuitively if one loss is a lot larger than the other, it will most likely dominate the gradient and with it the direction of the backprop. It would be helpful to look at the range of values for each loss, and then see if you can balance them out with scalars. In your question, `errG` seems already a lot smaller, and it has a factor of 0.1, whereas `errF` has a factor of 1.

Answer (score 1):

I work with some architecture which use several losses simultaneously and they adjust the weights for each loss function based on their importance and scale.

you can see example [fastpitch model](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples/blob/master/PyTorch/SpeechSynthesis/HiFiGAN/fastpitch/loss_function.py#L36)

```
loss = (mel_loss
                + dur_pred_loss * self.dur_predictor_loss_scale
                + pitch_loss * self.pitch_predictor_loss_scale
                + energy_loss * self.energy_predictor_loss_scale
                + attn_loss * self.attn_loss_scale)
```